# Datagrip Connection problems with SQL Server 2022 (v16)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, datagrip

I need to connect to my local instance of SQL Server from datagrip instead of SSMS.

With previous versions of SQL Server, I haven't had problems, but after changing laptop, I downloaded SQL Server 2022 and Datagrip 2023.2.3 and the problem started.

I followed the guide on [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html#step-1-configure-the-sql-server-configuration-manager)

But I get my connection is always refused. You can see my configuration here:

[Datagrip SSMS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyoIe.png)

The error is:

> [08S01] The connection to the host localhost, named instance MSI failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Since it is not clear to me why SSMS lets me in with server name MSI but everywhere else like in the services it is listed as `MSSQLSERVER` I tried both in datagrip, none worked.

Comment: udp/1434 is the SSRP port for the SQL Browser service, so it seems your code is attempting to connect using an instance name. If you know which port the instance is listening on you should be able to connect using `serverNameOrIpAddress:portNumber` (JDBC) or `serverNameOrIpAddress,portNumber` (ODBC). Unless you've been changing configurations the `MSSQLSERVER` instance listens on tcp/1433 by default.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion above, please ensure you have tcp/ip protocol enabled as per this article 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-protocols-tab?view=sql-server-ver16

If this won't, please upload the logs, and we'll have a look

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: AlwaysLearning I tried passing the port in the Host.
@Alexander Molchanov I double checked and tcp/ip is enabled, I think is also visible from the screenshot. Where do I get the logs? I'm opening a ticket as you suggested, I can copy the error message details  from the popup

Comment: Screenshots aren't generally visible for people on mobile devices, that's one of the many reasons their use is discouraged here. Now that I'm looking from a desktop machine... you don't specify an instance name in SSMS so why are you trying to specify one in DataGrip?

Comment: Update: testing the port with telnet I discovered that the sql port is closed, even if it is open from Sql Configuration Manager.
In the computer there is no additional software like antiviruses, How can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to [open port in Windows Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-firewall-for-report-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16) and [specify port 1433](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html#create_a_data_source) (default SQL Server TCP/IP port) in DataGrip.